# Calculating Business Hours between 2 times in R

Tags: r, datetime

I'm trying to calculate the hours between 2 times (a message create date and a message open date). I have used the following code to create a function

```
biz_hrs <- Vectorize(function(CreateDate, OpenedDate, starting_time = '8:00', ending_time = '17:00', holidays = NULL){
if(OpenedDate < CreateDate){
    
    return(NA)
    
  } else {
    
    start_datetime <- as.POSIXct(paste0(substr(start,1,11), starting_time, ':00'))
    end_datetime <- as.POSIXct(paste0(substr(end,1,11), ending_time, ':00'))
    
    if(as.Date(CreateDate) == as.Date(OpenedDate) & !as.Date(CreateDate) %in% holidays & !format(as.Date(CreateDate), "%u") %in% c(6,7)){ #if starting time stamp is on same day as ending time stamp and if day is not a holiday or weekend
      
      if(CreateDate > start_datetime & OpenedDate < end_datetime){ #if starting time stamp is later than start business hour and ending time stamp is earlier then ending business hour.
        return(as.numeric(difftime(OpenedDate, CreateDate), units = 'hours'))
      } else if(CreateDate > start_datetime & OpenedDate > end_datetime & CreateDate < end_datetime){ #if starting time stamp is later than end business hour and ending time stamp is earlier then ending business hour.
        return(as.numeric(difftime(as.POSIXct(paste0(substr(start,1,11), ending_time, ':00')), CreateDate), units = 'hours'))
      } else if(CreateDate < start_datetime & OpenedDate < end_datetime & OpenedDate > start_datetime){ #if starting time stamp is earlier than end business hour and ending time stamp is later than starting business hour.
        return(as.numeric(difftime(OpenedDate, start_datetime), units = 'hours'))
      } else if(CreateDate > end_datetime & OpenedDate > end_datetime){ #if starting time stamp is later than end business hour and ending time stamp is later than ending business hour.
        return(0)
      } else if(CreateDate < start_datetime & OpenedDate < start_datetime){ #if starting time stamp is earlier than start business hour and ending time stamp is earlier than starting business hour.
        return(0)
      } else {
        return(as.numeric(difftime(end_datetime, start_datetime), units = 'hours'))
      }
      
    } else { #if starting time stamp and ending time stamp occured on a different day.
      
      business_hrs <- as.numeric(difftime(as.POSIXct(paste0('2017-01-01', ending_time, ':00')),
                                          as.POSIXct(paste0('2017-01-01', starting_time, ':00')) #calculate business hours range by specified parameters
      ), units = 'hours')
      
      start_day_hrs <- ifelse(CreateDate < as.POSIXct(paste0(substr(start,1,11), ending_time, ':00')) & !as.Date(CreateDate) %in% holidays & !format(as.Date(CreateDate), "%u") %in% c(6,7), #if start time stamp is earlier than specified ending time
                              as.numeric(difftime(as.POSIXct(paste0(substr(start,1,11), ending_time, ':00')), CreateDate), units = 'hours'), #calculate time between time stamp and specified ending time
                              0 #else set zero
      ) #calculate amount of time on starting day
      start_day_hrs <- pmin(start_day_hrs, business_hrs) #cap the maximum amount of hours dertermined by the specified business hours
      start_day_hrs
      end_day_hrs <- ifelse(OpenedDate > as.POSIXct(paste0(substr(end,1,11), starting_time, ':00')) & !as.Date(OpenedDate) %in% holidays & !format(as.Date(OpenedDate), "%u") %in% c(6,7), #if end time stamp is later than specified starting time
                            as.numeric(difftime(end, as.POSIXct(paste0(substr(end,1,11), starting_time, ':00'))), units = 'hours'), #calculate time between time stamp and specified starting time
                            0) #calculate amount of time on ending day
      end_day_hrs <- pmin(end_day_hrs, business_hrs) #cap the maximum amount of hours dertermined by the specified business hours
      days_between <- seq(as.Date(CreateDate), as.Date(OpenedDate), by = 1) #create a vector of dates (from and up to including) the starting time stamp and ending time stamp
      business_days <- days_between[!days_between %in% c(as.Date(CreateDate), as.Date(OpenedDate)) & !days_between %in% holidays & !format(as.Date(days_between), "%u") %in% c(6,7)] #remove weekends and holidays from vector of dates
      
      return(as.numeric(((length(business_days) * business_hrs) + start_day_hrs + end_day_hrs))) #multiply the remaining number of days in the vector (business days) by the amount of business hours and add hours from the starting and end day. Return the result
      
    }
    
  }
  
  
})
```

and then entering in my data

```
Weekly_Final$ResponseTime <- biz_hrs(Weekly_Final$CreateDate, Weekly_Final$OpenedDate, '8:00', '17:00')
```

But I get the following error:

```
Error in as.character(x) : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'
```

Comment: Since we have no data to run this on and there is no indication where in that function the error occurs, I suggest: (1) define the function externally, `myfunc <- function(CreateDate,...){...}`; (2) then, do `debug(myfunc)`; and finally (3) `Vectorize(myfunc)(Weekly_Final$CreateDate,...)`. Try each line of your function, one-by-one, and find the one that produces this error. Once you find that, look at all of the arguments (variables/objects) that go into that line of code, and find the one that is not how you expect.

Answer (score 0):

You have made a mistake at some point when renaming variables. You are getting the error when calling `substr(start, 1, 11)` because there is no variable called `start`. R thinks you are referring to the *function* called `start`. I presume `CreateDate` used to be called `start` and `OpenedDate` used to be called `end`. If we just update these then the function returns an output

```r
biz_hrs <- Vectorize(function(CreateDate, OpenedDate, starting_time = '8:00', ending_time = '17:00', holidays = NULL){
if(OpenedDate < CreateDate){
    
    return(NA)
    
  } else {
    
    start_datetime <- as.POSIXct(paste0(substr(CreateDate,1,11), starting_time, ':00'))
    end_datetime <- as.POSIXct(paste0(substr(OpenedDate,1,11), ending_time, ':00'))
    
    if(as.Date(CreateDate) == as.Date(OpenedDate) & !as.Date(CreateDate) %in% holidays & !format(as.Date(CreateDate), "%u") %in% c(6,7)){ #if starting time stamp is on same day as ending time stamp and if day is not a holiday or weekend
      
      if(CreateDate > start_datetime & OpenedDate < end_datetime){ #if starting time stamp is later than start business hour and ending time stamp is earlier then ending business hour.
        return(as.numeric(difftime(OpenedDate, CreateDate), units = 'hours'))
      } else if(CreateDate > start_datetime & OpenedDate > end_datetime & CreateDate < end_datetime){ #if starting time stamp is later than end business hour and ending time stamp is earlier then ending business hour.
        return(as.numeric(difftime(as.POSIXct(paste0(substr(start,1,11), ending_time, ':00')), CreateDate), units = 'hours'))
      } else if(CreateDate < start_datetime & OpenedDate < end_datetime & OpenedDate > start_datetime){ #if starting time stamp is earlier than end business hour and ending time stamp is later than starting business hour.
        return(as.numeric(difftime(OpenedDate, start_datetime), units = 'hours'))
      } else if(CreateDate > end_datetime & OpenedDate > end_datetime){ #if starting time stamp is later than end business hour and ending time stamp is later than ending business hour.
        return(0)
      } else if(CreateDate < start_datetime & OpenedDate < start_datetime){ #if starting time stamp is earlier than start business hour and ending time stamp is earlier than starting business hour.
        return(0)
      } else {
        return(as.numeric(difftime(end_datetime, start_datetime), units = 'hours'))
      }
      
    } else { #if starting time stamp and ending time stamp occured on a different day.
      
      business_hrs <- as.numeric(difftime(as.POSIXct(paste0('2017-01-01', ending_time, ':00')),
                                          as.POSIXct(paste0('2017-01-01', starting_time, ':00')) #calculate business hours range by specified parameters
      ), units = 'hours')
      
      start_day_hrs <- ifelse(CreateDate < as.POSIXct(paste0(substr(CreateDate,1,11), ending_time, ':00')) & !as.Date(CreateDate) %in% holidays & !format(as.Date(CreateDate), "%u") %in% c(6,7), #if start time stamp is earlier than specified ending time
                              as.numeric(difftime(as.POSIXct(paste0(substr(CreateDate,1,11), ending_time, ':00')), CreateDate), units = 'hours'), #calculate time between time stamp and specified ending time
                              0 #else set zero
      ) #calculate amount of time on starting day
      start_day_hrs <- pmin(start_day_hrs, business_hrs) #cap the maximum amount of hours dertermined by the specified business hours
      start_day_hrs
      end_day_hrs <- ifelse(OpenedDate > as.POSIXct(paste0(substr(OpenedDate,1,11), starting_time, ':00')) & !as.Date(OpenedDate) %in% holidays & !format(as.Date(OpenedDate), "%u") %in% c(6,7), #if end time stamp is later than specified starting time
                            as.numeric(difftime(end, as.POSIXct(paste0(substr(OpenedDate,1,11), starting_time, ':00'))), units = 'hours'), #calculate time between time stamp and specified starting time
                            0) #calculate amount of time on ending day
      end_day_hrs <- pmin(end_day_hrs, business_hrs) #cap the maximum amount of hours dertermined by the specified business hours
      days_between <- seq(as.Date(CreateDate), as.Date(OpenedDate), by = 1) #create a vector of dates (from and up to including) the starting time stamp and ending time stamp
      business_days <- days_between[!days_between %in% c(as.Date(CreateDate), as.Date(OpenedDate)) & !days_between %in% holidays & !format(as.Date(days_between), "%u") %in% c(6,7)] #remove weekends and holidays from vector of dates
      
      return(as.numeric(((length(business_days) * business_hrs) + start_day_hrs + end_day_hrs))) #multiply the remaining number of days in the vector (business days) by the amount of business hours and add hours from the starting and end day. Return the result
      
    }
    
  }
  
})
```

So that:

```r
biz_hrs("2001-05-07", "2001-05-08")
#> 2001-05-07 
#>          9
```

I don't know whether this matches your expectations.

As an aside, you should check out the `lubridate` package, which would allow you to simplify and shorten your code. This will make debugging far easier.

I think the following simple function is a tidy replacement for `biz_hrs` that preserves the interface

```r
library(lubridate)

biz_hrs <- function(CreateDate, OpenedDate, start_time = '8:00', 
                    end_time = '17:00', holidays = NULL)
{
    begin    <- as.Date(CreateDate)
    end      <- as.Date(OpenedDate)
    hours    <- as.numeric(strsplit(end_time, ":")[[1]][1]) -
                as.numeric(strsplit(start_time, ":")[[1]][1])
    
    sapply(seq_along(begin), function(i) {
      if(begin[i] > end[i]) NA
      else {
        all_days <- seq(begin[i], end[i], "1 day")
        sum(hours * (wday(all_days) %in% 2:6 & is.na(match(all_days, holidays))))
      }})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on Allan's suggestion. The function is quite unwieldy. We can vectorize the function by using a combination of the `lubridate` and `bizdays` package. The problem is really finding the number of business days between two dates, adjusting for opening and closing hours. First of all we'd have to move days forward, to make sure they are within opening and closing hours.
With a bit of fiddling using the `hms` (hour-minute-second) class from lubridate, we can create a function to shift the dates.

```
library(lubridate)
library(bizdays)
cal <- create.calendar('mycal', weekdays = c('saturday', 'sunday'))
open <- hms('08:00:00')
close <- hms('17:00:00')
start <- as_datetime('2017-05-10 18:00:00') # After closing time, so real date = '2017-05-11 08:00:00'
end <- as_datetime('2017-05-11 12:00:00') # 4 hours after open

fix_biz_date <- function(date, open, close){
  if(!is.POSIXct(date))
    date <- lubridate::as_datetime(date)
  time <- hms(strftime(date, '%H:%M:%S'))  
  # Fix dates
  ind <- which(time >= close)
  if(length(ind) > 0)
    date[ind] <- date[ind] + days(1)
  # Fix times
  ind <- c(ind, which(time < open))
  if(length(ind) > 0){
    hour(date[ind]) <- hour(open)
    minute(date[ind]) <- minute(open)
    second(date[ind]) <- second(open)
  }
  date
}
fix_biz_date(start, open, close)
[1] "2017-05-11 08:00:00 UTC"
fix_biz_date(end, open, close)
[1] "2017-05-11 12:00:00 UTC"
```

Now that we have the dates shifted appropriately, we just need a function to find the number of business days and hours between the two.

```
#' @param start Starting date-time
#' @param end Ending date-time
#' @param cal calendar object (bizdays::create.calendar)
#' @param open hm(s) second object (lubridate::hms), specifying opening time of day
#' @param open hm(s) second object (lubridate::hms), specifying closing time of day
wh_diff <- function(start, end, cal, open, close){
  if(length(start) != length(end))
    stop('start and end needs to be of equal length!')
  if(!is.period(open))
    open <- hms(open)
  if(!is.period(close))
    close <- hms(close)
  start <- fix_biz_date(start, open, close)
  end <- fix_biz_date(end, open, close)
  sTime <- strftime(start, '%H:%M:%S')
  eTime <- strftime(end, '%H:%M:%S')
  days_dif <- bizdays(start, end, cal) 
  days_dif * (as.numeric(close - open) / 3600) + 
    as.numeric(hms(eTime) - hms(sTime)) / 3600
}
wh_diff(start, end, cal, open, close) # Expected 4 hours.
[1] 4
```

Now this function is actually vectorized appropriately, and will take an equal amount of start and ending dates or a single starting with multiple ending dates (or visa-versa).

```
end <- offset(end, seq(0, 180, length.out = 91), cal)
wh_diff(start, end, cal, open, close) # something like.. seq(0, 18 * 91, length.out = 91) 

start <- offset(start, 0:90, cal)
wh_diff(start, end, cal, open, close) # Expect seq(9, 9 * 91, length.out = 91)
```

This approach will be oceans of times faster than using `vectorize` which will create a couple of `for-loops` behind the scenes to get the job done. It did however require a bit of imagination and some experience working with dates.